# How to make \newframedtheorem{}{} with different color bar?

Tags: framed

I am creating this `\newframedtheorem{frm-ex}{Example}` and `\newframedtheorem{frm-excalculus}{Example}`

The result is both creating frame with same color of green. Can I change so the other is blue or dark red?

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{marginnote}
\usepackage[table, dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{regexpatch}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttb}{T1}{txtt}{bx}{n}{9}
\DeclareFixedFont{\ttm}{T1}{txtt}{m}{n}{9}  
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[amsmath,thmmarks,framed]{ntheorem} 
\newframedtheorem{frm-ex}{Example}
\newframedtheorem{frm-excalculus}{Example}
\renewcommand*\FrameCommand{{\color{green} \vrule width 3pt \hspace{17pt}}}


%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\begin{frm-ex}
    X
\end{frm-ex}


\begin{frm-excalculus}
    X
\end{frm-excalculus}

\end{document}
```

[image: 1]

Thanks.